# Regular Expressions: '\<' vs ' \b'

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Currently prepping for [RHCSA](https://www.redhat.com/en/services/certification/rhcsa) and learning *regex*. What's the difference between `\b` and `\<` ?

They seem to do almost the exact same thing: Match the string in between the backslashes.
Example:

```
[root@RHEL8DEV etc]# grep '\<root\>' * 2>/dev/null  | wc
    105     327    3658
```

```
[root@RHEL8DEV etc]# grep '\broot\b' * 2>/dev/null  | wc
    105     327    3658
```

Even after reading on [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org), I'm still scratching my head.

---

### Using `\b`

- `\b` matches the *empty string*, but only at the beginning or end of a word. Thus, `\bfoo\b` matches any occurrence of `foo` as a *separate* word. `\bballs?\b` matches `ball` or `balls` as a *separate* word. `\b` matches at the beginning or end of the buffer regardless of what
  text appears next to it.

### Using `\<` and `\>`

- `\<` atches the *empty string*, but only at the beginning of a
  word. `\<` matches at the beginning of the buffer only if a
  word-constituent character follows.
- `\>` matches the empty string, but only at the end of a word. `\>` matches at the end of the buffer only if the contents end with a word-constituent character.

---

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Comment: `grep` is not part of bash; it can be run with no shell even installed. Consider tagging `unix` instead, and specifying the specific OS vendor and version (or the grep version itself, if it's from a 3rd party like the GNU project).

Comment: Every tool will also specify what dialect of regular expression they understand. Neither `\b` nor `\<` have a universal meaning.

Comment: There's also a third option, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. It is supported in `grep` and `sed` in macOS and possibly the BSDs (I checked OpenBSD). Sadly, it's not supported by GNU.

Answer (score 4):

Only the manual page for your specific version of `grep` can reveal whether they are exactly equivalent. Neither is fully portable.

Traditionally, `\<` would *only* match at a lef word boundary, and `\>` at a right one, in some versions of `egrep`. (However, e.g. Procmail took a shortcut, and actually defines both identically.)

`\b` is a newer construct from Perl *et al.,* and is direction neutral, i.e. it is true at a word boundary either on the left or on the right of a sequence of word characters.

Comment: That last paragraph may be ambiguous. `\b` is essentially `(?:\<|\>)`

Comment: Of course, `(?:...)` is also a Perl extension. I don't see how this is ambiguous, but if it is, maybe your comment can help clarify it for somebody.

Comment: yeah, I should have said "`(\<|\>)` assuming extended regex" instead, and noted that PCRE doesn't support that (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038437/519360)). The ambiguity that I'm calling out is your use of "and" rather than "or"

Comment: Hm - thanks for the feedback; changed to use "or" instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've personally found `\b` to be more broadly supported than `\<` and `\>`. The only exceptions I've encountered is that vim and BSD sed support `\<` and `\>` without `\b`.

As to their definitions: in PCRE, it's essentially

- [`\<`](https://regex101.com/r/kH5Lqp/1) = [`(?<!\w)(?=\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/kH5Lqp/2) = word character on the right but *not* on the left
- [`\>`](https://regex101.com/r/suxRGV/1) = [`(?<=\w)(?!\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/suxRGV/2) = word character on the left but *not* on the right
- [`\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Lzpgus/1) = [`(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`](https://regex101.com/r/Lzpgus/2) = either of the above

Those links point to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)'s explanations of these regexes. Note that none of that site's four supported engines understand what `\<` and `\>` are supposed to do.

Since PCRE explicitly prohibits special meanings to non-alphanumeric escapes, `\<` means "literal open angle-bracket" and therefore `(?:\<|\>)` means `[<>]` rather than `\b`. Standard Extended Regular Expressions do not have this explicit prohibition, though they also do not implement any such special meanings (items like `\<` and `\>` are non-standard extensions).

Also note that inside a character class, things differ. In most regex interpreters, `[\b]` means "literal backspace character" and is equivalent to `[\010]` or `[\x08]` (or `\010` or `\x08`). Putting a zero-width item into a character class doesn't make any sense anyway.

An example of the differences, using GNU grep, which accepts both formats:

```sh
$ echo yes |grep '\<yes'
yes
$ echo yes |grep '\byes'
yes
$ echo yes |grep '\>yes'
# (no output here means it failed)
$
```

Here you can see that the directionality matters for `\<` and `\>` but not for `\b`

---

Various support tests, command-line only (Debian Testing as of 2019/11/25 or FreeBSD 11.2 as noted):

```sh
$ echo y |grep '\<y'       # GNU grep w/ BRE, Basic Regular Expression
y
$ echo y |grep -E '\<y'    # GNU grep w/ ERE, Extended Regular Expression
y
$ echo y |grep -P '\<y'    # GNU grep w/ libpcre, Perl-Compatible Regular Expression
$ echo y |perl -ne 'print if /\<y/'  # perl proper
$ echo y |sed '/\<y/!d'    # GNU sed with BRE
y
$ echo y |sed -r '/\<y/!d' # GNU sed with ERE
y
$ echo y |sed '/\<y/!d'    # BSD sed with BRE (FreeBSD 11.2)
y
$ echo y |sed -E '/\<y/!d' # BSD sed with ERE (FreeBSD 11.2)
y
$ echo y |gawk '/\<y/'     # GNU awk
y
$ echo y |mawk '/\<y/'     # More POSIX-aligned
$ 

# python test (result printed as an array, in this case empty for no matches)
$ echo y |python -c 'import re,sys; print re.findall(r"\<y", sys.stdin.read())'
[]
```

`grep -P` (which uses [libpcre](https://www.pcre.org/), not always compiled into grep) does not match because PCRE doesn't recognize `\<` as anything but a literal `<` character.

```sh
$ echo y |grep '\by'       # GNU grep w/ BRE, Basic regex
y
$ echo y |grep -E '\by'    # GNU grep w/ ERE, Extended regex
y
$ echo y |grep -P '\by'    # GNU grep w/ libpcre, Perl-compatible regex
y
$ echo y |perl -ne 'print if /\by/'  # perl proper 
y
$ echo y |sed '/\by/!d'    # GNU sed with BRE
y
$ echo y |sed -r '/\by/!d' # GNU sed with ERE
y
$ echo y |sed '/\by/!d'    # BSD sed with BRE (FreeBSD 11.2)
$ echo y |sed -E '/\by/!d' # BSD sed with ERE (FreeBSD 11.2)
$ echo y |gawk '/\by/'     # GNU awk
$ echo y |mawk '/\by/'     # POSIX-ish awk
$ 

# python test
$ echo y |python -c 'import re,sys; print re.findall(r"\by", sys.stdin.read())'
['y']
```

Note how BSD `sed` accepts `\<` but not `\b` yet GNU `sed` accepts both.

Comment: I tested on macOS 10.15 Catalina: `grep` supports both `\b` and `\<`/`\>`. `sed` and `awk` support neither.